# Telling from a symbol name whether a constant is a module

Tags: ruby, module, constants, symbols

If you know that a module (or class) `M` has a constant in its namespace whose name is represented by the symbol  `sym` (whose value is, for example, `:Foo`), what is the most efficient way to know whether that constant is a module (or class) or not? I came up with the following. Is there a better way?

```
M.const_get(sym).kind_of?(Module)
```

Comment: Your code is _perfect_.. :-)

Comment: I can't think of anything better, but could you not also use  `.respond_to? :m`, where `m` is any instance method that is unique to the class `Module` (of which there are many)? For example, `M.const_get?(sym).respond_to?(:ancestors)`. btw, I don't think `sym` is really relevant; you could have just as well written "..by the symbol `:Foo`, what is...". I'm taking a poll as to the number of times your first sentence must be read before it is understood.  For me, it was 7. (Not a criticism.)

Comment: Good point for `respond_to?`, but it may not be robust (if someone defined `ancestors` on a non-module). I used `sym` to give the impression that the actual content is unknown. The alternative I had in mind is to look through `ObjectSpace.each_object(Module)`, but was wondering if it is heavy.